# Downloading a file via JS results in a 0 byte file, why?

Tags: javascript, php

My script works like that :

- I make an AJAX call to a PHP script
- The PHP script process a lot of data and writes the result to a .csv file (via fopen/fwrite/fclose)
- When the PHP is done, I want my AJAX to open a download pop-up with the resulted file from the call

The last part is the problem here. When I try to make the user download the file, it just returns a 0 byte file. 
The problem doesn't come from my PHP script since the file on the server is correctly modified and is the result of the data processing.

I've tried window.open, window.location, appending an anchor with download attribute, download.js, delaying the download, server permissions, etc. Nothing works.

I don't want to go the blob way since it's a lot of server-side data processing, and even if I could, I'm still really wondering why the heck I always get a 0 byte file

My AJAX call :

```
$.ajax({
    url : './dataProcessing.php',
    type : 'POST',
    dataType : 'text',
    success : function(result, status){
        console.log(result); //Result being my file path
        console.log(status);
        window.open(result, '_self'); //One of the many things I've tried
    },
    error : function(result, status){
        console.log(result);
        console.log(status);
    }
});
```

My PHP globally consists of :

```
<?php
    $filename = 'myFile.csv';
    $resource = fopen($filename, 'w');
    //fwrite some lines
    fclose($resource);
    echo $filename;
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure `./foo/bar/myFile.csv` is the correct URL to the file in the server? Even if it is, hardcoding the file name like that, in your JavaScript, is a bad practice that you will, probably, regret at some later time. You should have your backend return the url for the recently created file, and use that on your success handler.

Comment: I was pretty sure of myself but you're right that it's bad practice. Edited my code and my post in consequence. Though it still doesn't work.